# Issue when creating Android keystore MAUI C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui, keystore

I can publish my app for Android from Visual Studio, but when I'm creating the Android keystore to sign it, I get the error on the screenshot.

[image: Keystore error]

I can't see the full description, neither know how to see the logs.

By the way, to publish and sign, I'm following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-google-play

Any idea how can I start troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, read this here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli
from start to end.

Then do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli#create-a-keystore-file, and post the error you get, if any.

If you have a working JDK (Java Development Kit) on some machine, you can use its keytool, even without Visual Studio.

(I am almost 100% sure that this is complaining about certificate chain)

Comment: Thank you for answering!
This is the error I got when following the 1st link: https://pastebin.com/nR32etu5
I didnt even start with the 2nd link because I got that error.
Will try with non ISO-8859-1 characters, let's see...

Comment: Finally!
Without ISO-8859-1 characters and running the command line as admin, I could create the keystore.
Will try to advance in signing my app with Visual Studio and if I'm done, I will mark this as the correct answer.